# compare a 2 string in c# using inbuilt method different case

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

How to compare a 2 string in different case
like
String a="Pawan";
String b="PAWAN";
how to compare using inbuilt method
I am try to compare culture method but can not be compere so please provide a solution
return result equal or not equal

Comment: By `compare` do you mean if they are equal or really compare in order to sort them?

Comment: @CSharpie `compare` and `really compare` - new word in string comparison history

Comment: Not to transform upper and lower case used any methods as inbuilt I don't know method name to compare directly without transfrom

Answer (score -1):

Transform both to lowercase strings and compare after that

```
a.ToLower() == b.ToLower()
```

Comment: This checks for equality and does not compare the two given strings.

Comment: @CSharpie What you mean ?

Comment: OP asked for `Compare`, your solution only checks equality. Compare is used to sort things.

Comment: Also using ToLower() in this way is bad practice.

Answer (score -1):

Every answer so far was checking for equality, here is mine actually comparing:

```
switch(string.Compare(a, b, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
{
   case  1: Console.WriteLine("a is greater"); break;
   case  0: Console.WriteLine("a and b are equal"); break;
   case -1: Console.WriteLine("b is greater"); break;
}
```

You can test it here https://dotnetfiddle.net/h75xZ8

If you arent sure about the comparison, you can look it up here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison(v=vs.110).aspx